# Can I leave Italy to non-schengen area while waiting for my first issue residence permit

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, oman, residence-permits

I have single entry visa and I've applied for may residence permit but my fingerprint appointment have been reschedule after 3 months.

Due to urgent circumstances I need to fly to my home country before my fingerprint appointment and my home country is non schengen country.

Can I leave and return to Italy with my post office receipt?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella The prior question is related, but is not a duplicate: the prior question's OP has visa-free entry (by virtue of their passport) into Italy; the OP here requires a visa, and has only a single-entry one. Once this OP leaves, they cannot reenter if the post office receipt is insufficient...which is the OP's question.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica The duped answer states exactly that and is not dependant on visa requirements. They can reenter Italy showing their expired visa sticker and the PO Receipt

Comment: @NicolasFormichella The fourth comment (under the original post in the referenced question) indicates the OP in that question has (or will have, after the OP's planned trip) the ability to enter Italy using their home-country passport, which is eligible for visa-free entry into Schengen countries. I think that difference puts the OP of this question in a different category, as the OP here does not have visa-free entry privileges.

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica The comments, yes, the answer no